# Why do I get an error message when trying to assign a rect to a surface?

Tags: python, pygame, surface, rect

I'm making a game and adding enemies to them, but for some reason, when I try to use the .get_rect() method, I get an error message saying "invalid rect assignment". I've tried many ways, if you can find a way to fix it, please let me know. Also, please, do feel free to criticise my work, as long as you provide me with solutions to fix that. I really want to improve.

```
python
class enemy():
    def __init__(self, x, y, eid):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.eid = eid
        self.enemysurf = pygame.image.load("graphics/enemy.png")
        self.enemyrect = self.enemysurf.get_rect(center=(self.x, self.y) # I get the error message here
        screen.blit(self.enemysurf, self.enemyrect)
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message / the line where the error shows up? Also, try to give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not the whole code.

Comment: @nonlinear, did that, do you think you'd be able to answer the question now? If so, please, do.

Comment: `self.enemyrect = self.enemysurf.get_rect(center=(self.x, self.y))` - you missed 1 parentheses at the end

Comment: @Rabbid76, it works but now the game window is completely black, also, can you please give your answer in the form of an answer, not a comment? Thanks.

Comment: @bix No the problem is a typo. Typo questions should not be answered, but closed and not answered as they are not helpful to other contributor,

Comment: @Rabbid76, sorry, I'm new to Stack Overflow, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is just a missing close parenthesis. This code should work:

<s>`self.enemyrect = self.enemysurf.get_rect(center=(self.x, self.y)`</s>

```py
self.enemyrect = self.enemysurf.get_rect(center=(self.x, self.y))
```

Also, calling `.convert()` on `pygame.image.load("graphics/enemy.png")` makes the code faster. Lastly, if I remember your initial code correctly, you should always put the 'import' statements at the beginning of your code. More on [the python style guide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)

Comment: Great job you managed to turn my comment into an answer. Typo questions should not be answered, but closed as they are not helpful to other contributors.